# Reading request body inside custom InvalidModelStateResponseFactory asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to fetch HTTP request body inside my custom `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` handler and it's always return empty.
I tried so many solutions in SO and other websites but it seems using `EnableRewind` has no effect inside `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`.
So is there any special cases that i can fetch request body inside `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`?

*My Code in Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
        {
            actionContext.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();
            using(StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
            {
                string body = stream.ReadToEnd();    //body is always empty
            }

            return new BadRequestObjectResult(/*Some Error Model*/);
        };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm able to make the example you've provided work with a simple change, by replacing:

```
actionContext.HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();
```

with:

```
actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
```

Once the body has been read (by MVC itself), the stream's position needs to be reset to the beginning before attempting to read it again.

In my testing, I found that I didn't need a call to `EnableRewind` *at all*, but in case this is needed in your case, I expect it's being called *too late* in your example. If setting `Position` to `0` as I've shown doesn't work alone, you might need to add a custom middleware that sets up rewind:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.Request.EnableRewind();
    await next();
});
```

This would need to be added before `UseMvc`, but as I've said, I found in my testing it wasn't needed but I expect that will not always be the case.

Comment: wow this actually works without need to call `EnableRewind`!, but can you explain to me why there is no need to call `EnableRewind`? i thought you can't read request body stream again without calling it.

Comment: also in [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/re-reading-asp-net-core-request-bodies-with-enablebuffering/) Microsoft suggested to use `EnableBuffering()`, i tried that with no effect. what was the purpose of `EnableBuffering()` and `EnableRewind()` then?

Comment: It looks like the `JsonInputFormatter` itself (which reads your body when model-binding, etc) actually calls `EnableBuffering` for you ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Mvc/Mvc.Formatters.Json/src/JsonInputFormatter.cs#L245)). Calling it yourself would be used in more advanced scenarios, when you want to read the body before it goes to MVC, etc.